# Change the stylemap styles after cloning

Tags: openlayers-2, style

I'm creating bearing lines with labels.

The style is set for all markup using the styleMap

I am cloning the styleMap so that the labels don't get overwritten each time the page does a redraw - which is every 3 seconds or when the map refreshes

I want to be able to have the same style as the original styleMap, however, after the clone, the lines come out black and creating another styleMap doesn't seem to work either

```js
getBearingLabel : function(feature)
{
    feature.style = Object.clone(this.style);
    var point1 = feature.geometry.components[0];
    var point2 = feature.geometry.components[1];
    var midPoint = FindMidPoint(point1.y, point1.x, point2.y, point2.x);
    var midPosition = this.map.getPixelFromLonLat(new OpenLayers.LonLat(midPoint.lon, midPoint.lat));
    var length = GCDistance(point1.y, point1.x, point2.y, point2.x).toFixed(2);
    var point1Position = this.map.getPixelFromLonLat(new OpenLayers.LonLat(point1.x, point1.y));
    var bearing1 = GetForwardBearing(point1.y, point1.x, point2.y, point2.x);
    if (bearing1 < 0)
    {
        var fullCircle = 360;
        bearing1 += fullCircle;
    }
    feature.style.labelXOffset = -(point1Position.x - midPosition.x);
    feature.style.labelYOffset = point1Position.y - midPosition.y;
    feature.style.label = "Bearing: " + bearing1.toFixed(2) + "°\n" + "Distance: " +    length + "nmi";
}
```

Is it possible to set a default, select and delete style that don't affect the original styleMap?

Answer (score 1):

On this page it is well explained how to define a stylemap:
http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/olstyle.html  .just use the given example for setting the default style and do it again for the select style. So you set the style for the whole layer and don't have to define it for every single feature.

Comment: I know how to set a styleMap, but when adding a label, the style needs to be cloned so that when more bearing lines are added, the original label isn't overwritten.

This occurs because I am adding additional attributes to the styleMap, labelXOffset